# Combine two Byte Image data into a single PDF and then download or print the PDF

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, image, pdf

I am doing an ASP.NET website to book tickets and then download them. I have a predefined payment voucher and the ticket for this, that I have converted into images. During the time of booking a ticket the details such as name, amount, etc. will be written on these images and saved in the database in "byte" (varbinary) format. I am using the below code for this.

```
StringFormat stringformat = new StringFormat();
stringformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
stringformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
Color StringColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");

System.Drawing.Image creditBitmap = (System.Drawing.Image)Bitmap.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/voucher.jpg"));
Graphics creditImage = Graphics.FromImage(creditBitmap);
creditImage.DrawString(name, new Font("arial", 12,
FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(StringColor), new Point(160, 519),
stringformat);
creditImage.DrawString(amount, new Font("arial", 12,
FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(StringColor), new Point(320, 181),
stringformat);

Response.ContentType = "~/Images/voucher1.jpg";
byte[] credit = (byte[])(new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(creditBitmap, typeof(byte[]));
```

Then I am inserting this value into the SQL table "UploadedFiles" inside the column "Voucher". In the same way, I am also generating another image for the ticket using the same process and insert it into the column name "Ticket".

Now I want to download the voucher and ticket combined as a single PDF. I am using the following code to fetch them from the database and convert them to byte array on a button click.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("select * from UploadedFiles where BookingID=@id", con);
select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", bookingID);
SqlDataReader data = select.ExecuteReader();
data.Read();
byte[] voucher = (byte[])data["Voucher"];
byte[] ticket = (byte[])data["Ticket"];
image_voucher.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(voucher, 0, voucher.Length);
image_ticket.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ticket, 0, ticket.Length);
con.Close();
```

These two images are getting displayed in the web page. But now I want to download them both as a single PDF file. The resolutions of both the images are 800 x 480 and I want to place them in a single page of the PDF. Also after generating the PDF, I should have both the option to download it or print it directly using two different buttons. How can I do this? is there any easy approach?

I want to have two buttons one for download and another for print. When I click on download button the images should be fetched from the database, converted into a single PDF and downloaded automatically. On clicking print button the images should be fetched from the database, converted into a single PDF and this PDF should be prompted for print.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itextsharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) lib to make one pdf with x amount of pictures in it.

Using the following code:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

//pdfpath is the full path of where you want the pdf to be created
//keep in mind to check for directory existence
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();

//files is a list of your files as FileInfo
foreach (var file in files)
{
  try
  {
    Image docImage = Image.GetInstance(file.FullName);
    //scale the images to fit the document size
    docImage.ScaleToFit(doc.PageSize.Width, doc.PageSize.Height);
    docImage.Alignment = Image.ALIGN_CENTER; //align the pictures
    doc.Add(docImage);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //exception handle logic
  }
  finally
  {
     doc.close();
  }      
}
```